# Find and Replace in Notepad++ including an EOL or CRLF character

Tags: windows

I have many files that have been created with CRLF's at the end of every line. I want to seprate these back into their original paragraphs by taking out the CRLF's (or other EOL characters) based on a rule.

I want to start by replacing any lower case character followed by a CRLF with the (found) lowercase character and a space. So in an example this would look like this;

Data
Thank you very much Doctor, thast would be very kind ofCRLF
you and I am sure the othe guests would also welcome youCRLF
taking the time to speak to each of them and answer theirCRLF
quetions.

Result
Thank you very much Doctor, thast would be very kind of you and I am sure the othe guests would also welcome you taking the time to speak to each of them and answer their quetions.

I have tried various combinations of ([a-z])$, ([\l])$ and combinations using "\n\r" and "\r\n" with the ([a-z]) but with no luck.

Any pointers to help would be most welcome !

Thanks very much for reading.

Answer (score 1):

#### I want to separate these back into their original paragraphs by taking out the CRLF's (or other EOL characters)

- Menu "Search" > "Replace" (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>)
- Set "Find what" to `([a-z])\R`.
- Set "Replace with" to `\1`
- Enable "Regular expression" and "matches newline"
- Click "Replace All"

Notes:

- Use `\r\n` for Windows EOLs
- Use `\n` for Unix/OSX EOLs
- Use `\r` for Mac OS (up to version 9) EOLs
- Alternatively use `\R` which should work on every OS

[image]

Before:

```
Thank you very much Doctor, thast would be very kind of
 you and I am sure the othe guests would also welcome you
 taking the time to speak to each of them and answer their
 quetions.
```

After:

```
Thank you very much Doctor, thast would be very kind of you and I am sure the othe guests would also welcome you taking the time to speak to each of them and answer their quetions.
```

---

#### Further reading

- [How to use regular expressions in Notepad++ (tutorial)](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions)
- [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)
- [Regular Expressions Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)
- [RegExr: Learn, Build, & Test RegEx](http://regexr.com/)
- [regex101: Online regex tester and debugger](https://regex101.com/)
- [RegExper: Regular Expression Visualiser](https://regexper.com/)

Comment: Do you need more help? If this answered your question, please don't forget to [accept the answer](https://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking the accept button (the tick ✓ button).